# can't install Windows from USB - stuck on the purple/blue screen on installation

Tags: windows, boot, installation, bios, windows-installation

I have previously double-partioned system with Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 7 in parallel (and GRUB of course) and everything works fine, but after I change my motherboard to new one X79 - Windows stops loading with BSOD (Ubuntu still works perfectly fine). I decide to make a fresh installation, create bootable USB from official image, but every attempt to start installation process stuck on blue screen for Win7 and purple for Win10 (i.e. just the background image during installation). I can move my mouse and see cursor, but nothing happen even after I wait some time.

I actually does a lot of research and made plenty of attempts. What I try:

- use different USBs (3 of them) and images (Win7 and Win10) with the same effect
- try to use the same USBs on my friend's laptopt to see if installation worked - and it did, so I doubt the reason in USB/image/program used to write image
- try to plug out all disks except one to which I want to install Windows (in total 2 SSD + 1 HDD)
- try to Shift+F10 during this purple/blue screen - and it works, cmd appears. I try to run `diskpart` command - it just waits forever after a couple of welcome words (expect to see prompt again), `list` is not a working command at all (I am not too good in win cmd, so maybe this is ok)
- finally, try to play with BIOS setting, switch on and off Fast Boot and Quiet Boot, but it does not help

I actually strongly suspect that there is something with the BIOS settings (probably between Legacy/UEFI options) and correct combination should solve the problem, but can't figure out it by myself, so I attach pictures of Boot tab and CSM parameters in the BIOS screen:

[Bot tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLbLL.jpg)

[CSM tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdOpQ.jpg)

I also try to switch CSM off (find this advice somewhere), but to do this the change in video settings need to be done first and every time I try to do that all displays stop working after restart (so I need to go inside my PC and eject CMOS to restart BIOS, which is not a pleasant experience since it is located under video card).

Comment: Did you solve it? I have the same issue.